# React Native refs and constructors

Tags: javascript, react-native, constructor, components, ref

I'm new to react native and want to ask some questions. First of all sorry if they are dumb. :(

I've been watching and trying to learn react native through some video courses and I found this https://blog.expo.io/introducing-expo-ar-mobile-augmented-reality-with-javascript-powered-by-arkit-b0d5a02ff23
guide while I was surfing. I copied and pasted the code and tried to learn it by deleting some lines to figure out what they are doing. When I delete the "ref" line camera didn't work. I actually couldn't understand why is it like that. So decided to ask it here. While asking it, I thought it will be good to ask other questions. So here are the questions:

What is ref and when to use it and when to not?

What is constructor and when to use it and when to not?

Thanks for your answers already!

The code is:

```
`
import Expo from 'expo';
import React from 'react';

import * as THREE from 'three'; // 0.87.1
import ExpoTHREE from 'expo-three'; // 2.0.2

console.disableYellowBox = true;

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Expo.GLView
        ref={(ref) => this._glView = ref}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        onContextCreate={this._onGLContextCreate}
      />
    );
  }

  _onGLContextCreate = async (gl) => {
    const width = gl.drawingBufferWidth;
    const height = gl.drawingBufferHeight;

    const arSession = await this._glView.startARSessionAsync();

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = ExpoTHREE.createARCamera(arSession, width, height, 0.01, 1000);
    const renderer = ExpoTHREE.createRenderer({ gl });
    renderer.setSize(gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight);

    scene.background = ExpoTHREE.createARBackgroundTexture(arSession, renderer);

    // Edit the box dimensions here and see changes immediately!
    const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.07, 0.07, 0.07);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    cube.position.z = -0.4;
    scene.add(cube);

    const animate = () => {
      requestAnimationFrame(animate);

      cube.rotation.x += 0.07;
      cube.rotation.y += 0.04;

      renderer.render(scene, camera);
      gl.endFrameEXP();
    }
    animate();
  }
}
`
```

Comment: Hey John, welcome to StackOverflow! Try to include some code in the actual question so that people don't need to take extra steps to see the code you are referring to. From what I recall constructors in react are just like constructors in other languages - you use them to perform tasks needed during instantiation. As for what a `ref` is: you are very likely to find such answers in the official docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html. Good luck with your learning :)

Comment: @WilliamPatton thank you for a warm welcome and quick answer! I updated my question :)

Answer (score 0):

(1) ref is for you to save a reference to a component, so it's accessible from other components.

As a simplified example, consider a sign in page. When the user presses enter after typing the email, he/she may expect to continue to type the password. To do that, you'll need a ref to the password TextInput component

```
          <TextInput
            autoFocus
            keyboardType="email-address"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            returnKeyType="next"
            onChangeText={t => this.setState({ email: t })}
            onSubmitEditing={(event) => {
              this.passwordTextInput.focus();
            }}
          />

          <TextInput
            secureTextEntry
            autoCapitalize="none"
            returnKeyType="done"
            onChangeText={t => this.setState({ password: t })}
            ref={(c) => { this.passwordTextInput = c; }}
            onSubmitEditing={(event) => {
              this.signIn();
            }}
          />
```

So basically if you don't need the component to be accessed, then there's no need to specify ref.

(2) constructor, as the name suggests, is the object constructor of the component object. It's for initializing states. Please reference [the doc of react.js](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor); it's the same for react native.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer but what is the c argument in the ref?

Comment: It refers to the TextInput component itself. You can name it anything. So what you assign to ref, is a function that takes one object as parameter.

Comment: So is it like the name property in html?

Comment: Yes conceptually. Just assign it's value to some other variable, then you can access it by that variable.